# PyCharm and debugging private attributes

Tags: python, pycharm

I use PyCharm Community Edition 3.4.

I have added `self.__a` to Watches.

This is my example:

```
class Box:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.__a = a
        self._b  = b
        self.c   = c
        d = 0 #Breakpoint.


a = Box(1, 2, 3)
```

So, I start debugging and stop at the breakpoint. The `self.__a` watch shows `{AttributeError}'Box' object has no attribute 'a'.`

I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> and evaluate `self.__a = a`. The result is `None`.

Then I evaluate `self.__a` and the result is `1`.

My watch for `self.__a` still shows `{AttributeError}'Box' object has no attribute 'a'`. I delete it. Then I add another watch `self.__a`. It shows `1`.

Could you clarify what is going on here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

it is because box has no `__a`

it gets name mangled ...

see also: [Name_mangling#Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Python)

it becomes

```
Box._Box__a
```

and if you change it to watch

```
self._Box__a
```

it will show you the proper value

but it should also show up in the variables list view (in the center of the debug run panel)